# React Native Touchable Icon

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I want to implement an Menu Icon from MaterialIcon in my Header and when I tap this Icon I want to open a menu. The problem is, if I add margin or something else to this Icon to position the icon, the Touchable onPress is not working properly. First I had absolute Positioning with zIndex and the onPress was not triggered every time. Let's say of tapping 100 times the onPress was trigged for 3 times. I have figured out the same behaviour with relative positioning and margin. I also tried to implement Touchables from react-native-gestures or from react-native. In the moment I remove margin the Touchable works correctly. The onPress get's triggered every time I press this icon. Very curious. What's wrong? Do someone know this issue?

This is my Code:

```
<StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
<ScreenCmpt style={styles.container}>
   <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("test")}>
       <View style={styles.menuContainer}>
          <MaterialIcons style={styles.menu} name="menu" size={30} />
       </View>
     </TouchableOpacity>
    ....

headerContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 15,
    fontFamily: "CinzelDecorative_400Regular",
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  menuContainer: {
    marginLeft: height * -0.13,
  },
  menu: {
    color: colors.primary,
    alignSelf: "center",
    // marginLeft: height * -0.13,
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amir has some good debugging information there, and it is worth knowing and using in the future. That being said, just because you can see where your touchable locations are doesn't mean you'll understand what is wrong.

I personally do not 'know' what is wrong, but my guess is by adding a margin, you are moving your icon out of the touchable container. I would recommend adding your positioning styles to the `TouchableOpacity` instead of your icon. This should move the whole button over, instead of just its contents since it is possible to move the contents outside of a parent container.

Comment: Hmm the thing is, when I run this code on iOS Simulator the Touchable Works but if try it out on my device, the touchable has this behaviour I've explained

Comment: So, after moving the margin to the touchable opacity, you still get the issue on physical devices? Or are you saying that it was only on physical devices before the change?

Comment: Yes it was only on the physical device. But you where right, I moved the icon out of touchable container. I found out with the help of Amir. But what I don't understand is why it worked on iOS Simulator although the icon was outside the touchable container. Anyway. Now it's working. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

dear i will not edit your codes and i want yourself to do it , so you will also be able to debug your codes and find problems and solve them .

There is react native debug menu embedded with react native apps ! for your situation on Android **ctrl(cmd) + M** and on IOS **ctrl(cmd) + D** will open up the below popup

[image: Debug Mode looks like this]

then click on ***show inspector*** and from the menu there choose ***touchable*** then you will see this your app looking like :

[image: touchable debug mode]

now click on the part you want to check the touchable and see where is your touchable located at ! I am sure you will understand and do the rest

Comment: Thank you for your input! When I click on Touchable I get the error variable Animated not found? What does this mean?

Comment: you are using animated somewhere in your components and you didnt import it

Comment: I use Animated for Video Background. How should I import Animated? If I reload the project it's working. I don't understand this error.

Comment: you can also put your codes on github and leave a link here i will help you

Comment: @AmirDoreh can you send me your email I want to talk with you

Comment: drhemir@gmail.com